# Jquery: Extract JSON data and build dropdownlist in Bootstrap v3 modal

Tags: jquery, json, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to extract data from a JSON file which contains address information from a GIS postcode lookup.

The code that I currently have got to is:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var success = function(responseData) {
        var string = JSON.stringify(responseData);

        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = string;
        document.getElementById("address").innerHTML = string;
    };

    var runRequest = function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "https:THIS IS WHERE THE GIS LOOKUP HAPPENS",
            data: {

                "where" : "PostcodeLocator='" + $('#postcode').val() + "'",
                "outFields" : "UPRN, PaoStartNumber, StreetDescription, TownName, AdministrativeArea, PostcodeLocator",
                "returnGeometry" : true,
                "outSR" : 4326,
                "f" : "json"
            },
            success: success,
            dataType: "jsonp"
        });
    };
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input name="postcode" id="postcode" type="text" placeholder="enter postcode" />
<span></span>
<button onclick='runRequest();'>Get Address</button>
<br />
<textarea name="extract" id="extract" COLS=80 rows="5"></textarea><p>
<textarea name="address" id="address" COLS=80 rows="30"></textarea>

<div id="result">(This will get replaced with response data)</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I can get the JSON to be passed to the DIV and to the address textarea, but cannot work out how to get a specific datafield from the JSON. I have tried the following:

```
obj = JSON.parse(responseData);

alert(obj.displayFieldName);

alert(string.displayFieldName);

//document.getElementById("extract").innerHTML = "bye"
document.getElementById("extract").innerHTML = "-" + data.features[0].attributes.StreetDescription + "-";
```

I also came across this:

```
$.each(json, function(idx, obj) {
alert(obj.tagName);
});
```

What am I missing (something probably fairly basic) to be able to extract and build a Street Address that can then be passed to a selectlist in a Bootstrap modal?

The JSON is complicated and is provided with no spaces. The JSON is below:

To aid in the reading of the JSON I have found two very useful sites that format and parse the JSON:

[JSON Parser 1](http://json.parser.online.fr/) 
and [JSON Parser 2](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/)

```
{"displayFieldName":"OrganisationName","fieldAliases":{"Uprn":"Uprn","PaoStartNumber":"PaoStartNumber","StreetDescription":"StreetDescription","TownName":"TownName","AdministrativeArea":"AdministrativeArea","PostcodeLocator":"PostcodeLocator"},"geometryType":"esriGeometryPoint","spatialReference":{"wkid":4326,"latestWkid":4326},"fields":[{"name":"Uprn","type":"esriFieldTypeString","alias":"Uprn","length":12},{"name":"PaoStartNumber","type":"esriFieldTypeInteger","alias":"PaoStartNumber"},{"name":"StreetDescription","type":"esriFieldTypeString","alias":"StreetDescription","length":100},{"name":"TownName","type":"esriFieldTypeString","alias":"TownName","length":30},{"name":"AdministrativeArea","type":"esriFieldTypeString","alias":"AdministrativeArea","length":30},{"name":"PostcodeLocator","type":"esriFieldTypeString","alias":"PostcodeLocator","length":8}],"features":[{"attributes":{"Uprn":"10001271958","PaoStartNumber":null,"StreetDescription":"CAMBRIDGE CLOSE","TownName":"HOUNSLOW","AdministrativeArea":"LONDON BOROUGH OF HOUNSLOW","PostcodeLocator":"TW4 7BH"},"geometry":{"x":-0.38466223515548237,"y":51.46641840116879}},{"attributes":{"Uprn":"100021542925","PaoStartNumber":150,"StreetDescription":"CAMBRIDGE ROAD","TownName":"HOUNSLOW","AdministrativeArea":"LONDON BOROUGH OF HOUNSLOW","PostcodeLocator":"TW4 7BH"},"geometry":{"x":-0.38495835709298737,"y":51.466227347041404}},{"attributes":{"Uprn":"100021542897","PaoStartNumber":104,"StreetDescription":"CAMBRIDGE ROAD","TownName":"HOUNSLOW","AdministrativeArea":"LONDON BOROUGH OF HOUNSLOW","PostcodeLocator":"TW4 7BH"},"geometry":{"x":-0.3832720999958992,"y":51.46648287075978}},{"attributes":{"Uprn":"100023404850","PaoStartNumber":130,"StreetDescription":"CAMBRIDGE ROAD","TownName":"HOUNSLOW","AdministrativeArea":"LONDON BOROUGH OF HOUNSLOW","PostcodeLocator":"TW4 7BH"},"geometry":{"x":-0.3843542291007974,"y":51.466293660648766}},{"attributes":{"Uprn":"100021542916","PaoStartNumber":126,"StreetDescription":"CAMBRIDGE ROAD","TownName":"HOUNSLOW","AdministrativeArea":"LONDON BOROUGH OF HOUNSLOW","PostcodeLocator":"TW4 7BH"},"geometry":{"x":-0.38416279147223714,"y":51.46633328658705}},{"attributes":{"Uprn":"100021542895","PaoStartNumber":102,"StreetDescription":"CAMBRIDGE ROAD","TownName":"HOUNSLOW","AdministrativeArea":"LONDON BOROUGH OF HOUNSLOW","PostcodeLocator":"TW4 7BH"},"geometry":{"x":-0.38318550668659545,"y":51.46648887063152}},{"attributes":{"Uprn":"100021542876","PaoStartNumber":76,"StreetDescription":"CAMBRIDGE ROAD","TownName":"HOUNSLOW","AdministrativeArea":"LONDON BOROUGH OF HOUNSLOW","PostcodeLocator":"TW4 7BH"},"geometry":{"x":-0.3822963348060751,"y":51.46659530526205}},{"attributes":{"Uprn":"100021542905","PaoStartNumber":112,"StreetDescription":"CAMBRIDGE ROAD","TownName":"HOUNSLOW","AdministrativeArea":"LONDON BOROUGH OF HOUNSLOW","PostcodeLocator":"TW4 7BH"},"geometry":{"x":-0.38354363597824703,"y":51.466417373567936}},{"attributes":{"Uprn":"100021542923","PaoStartNumber":146,"StreetDescription":"CAMBRIDGE ROAD","TownName":"HOUNSLOW","AdministrativeArea":"LONDON BOROUGH OF HOUNSLOW","PostcodeLocator":"TW4 7BH"},"geometry":{"x":-0.38485840110444585,"y":51.46624485409831}},{"attributes":{"Uprn":"100021542879","PaoStartNumber":78,"StreetDescription":"CAMBRIDGE ROAD","TownName":"HOUNSLOW","AdministrativeArea":"LONDON BOROUGH OF HOUNSLOW","PostcodeLocator":"TW4 7BH"},"geometry":{"x":-0.3823414202260057,"y":51.466582438794184}},{"attributes":{"Uprn":"100021542907","PaoStartNumber":114,"StreetDescription":"CAMBRIDGE ROAD","TownName":"HOUNSLOW","AdministrativeArea":"LONDON BOROUGH OF HOUNSLOW","PostcodeLocator":"TW4 7BH"},"geometry":{"x":-0.38361702418438853,"y":51.466418385250606}},{"attributes":{"Uprn":"100021542869","PaoStartNumber":66,"StreetDescription":"CAMBRIDGE ROAD","TownName":"HOUNSLOW","AdministrativeArea":"LONDON BOROUGH OF HOUNSLOW","PostcodeLocator":"TW4 7BH"},"geometry":{"x":-0.38191236399578693,"y":51.46666464346716}},{"attributes":{"Uprn":"100021542872","PaoStartNumber":70,"StreetDescription":"CAMBRIDGE ROAD","TownName":"HOUNSLOW","AdministrativeArea":"LONDON BOROUGH OF HOUNSLOW","PostcodeLocator":"TW4 7BH"},"geometry":{"x":-0.3820544977556467,"y":51.46663513166532}},{"attributes":{"Uprn":"100021542893","PaoStartNumber":100,"StreetDescription":"CAMBRIDGE ROAD","TownName":"HOUNSLOW","AdministrativeArea":"LONDON BOROUGH OF HOUNSLOW","PostcodeLocator":"TW4 7BH"},"geometry":{"x":-0.383121841835379,"y":51.46649788430216}},{"attributes":{"Uprn":"100021542911","PaoStartNumber":118,"StreetDescription":"CAMBRIDGE ROAD","TownName":"HOUNSLOW","AdministrativeArea":"LONDON BOROUGH OF HOUNSLOW","PostcodeLocator":"TW4 7BH"},"geometry":{"x":-0.3837966967170755,"y":51.466385791886694}},{"attributes":{"Uprn":"100021542921","PaoStartNumber":142,"StreetDescription":"CAMBRIDGE ROAD","TownName":"HOUNSLOW","AdministrativeArea":"LONDON BOROUGH OF HOUNSLOW","PostcodeLocator":"TW4 7BH"},"geometry":{"x":-0.3847545406681164,"y":51.46625061727953}},{"attributes":{"Uprn":"200003984587","PaoStartNumber":null,"StreetDescription":"CAMBRIDGE ROAD","TownName":"HOUNSLOW","AdministrativeArea":"LONDON BOROUGH OF HOUNSLOW","PostcodeLocator":"TW4 7BH"},"geometry":{"x":-0.3834231203595149,"y":51.466446285982}},{"attributes":{"Uprn":"100021542918","PaoStartNumber":130,"StreetDescription":"CAMBRIDGE ROAD","TownName":"HOUNSLOW","AdministrativeArea":"LONDON BOROUGH OF HOUNSLOW","PostcodeLocator":"TW4 7BH"},"geometry":{"x":-0.3834231203595149,"y":51.466446285982}},{"attributes":{"Uprn":"200003967289","PaoStartNumber":null,"StreetDescription":"CAMBRIDGE ROAD","TownName":"HOUNSLOW","AdministrativeArea":"LONDON BOROUGH OF HOUNSLOW","PostcodeLocator":"TW4 7BH"},"geometry":{"x":-0.38343751021175665,"y":51.46644648436965}},{"attributes":{"Uprn":"200003982411","PaoStartNumber":76,"StreetDescription":"CAMBRIDGE ROAD","TownName":"HOUNSLOW","AdministrativeArea":"LONDON BOROUGH OF HOUNSLOW","PostcodeLocator":"TW4 7BH"},"geometry":{"x":-0.3834231203595149,"y":51.466446285982}},{"attributes":{"Uprn":"200003982412","PaoStartNumber":76,"StreetDescription":"CAMBRIDGE ROAD","TownName":"HOUNSLOW","AdministrativeArea":"LONDON BOROUGH OF HOUNSLOW","PostcodeLocator":"TW4 7BH"},"geometry":{"x":-0.3834231203595149,"y":51.466446285982}},{"attributes":{"Uprn":"100023661861","PaoStartNumber":null,"StreetDescription":"CAMBRIDGE ROAD","TownName":"HOUNSLOW","AdministrativeArea":"LONDON BOROUGH OF HOUNSLOW","PostcodeLocator":"TW4 7BH"},"geometry":{"x":-0.3834231203595149,"y":51.466446285982}},{"attributes":{"Uprn":"100021542919","PaoStartNumber":130,"StreetDescription":"CAMBRIDGE ROAD","TownName":"HOUNSLOW","AdministrativeArea":"LONDON BOROUGH OF HOUNSLOW","PostcodeLocator":"TW4 7BH"},"geometry":{"x":-0.3843644924306207,"y":51.46628840667688}},{"attributes":{"Uprn":"100021542874","PaoStartNumber":74,"StreetDescription":"CAMBRIDGE ROAD","TownName":"HOUNSLOW","AdministrativeArea":"LONDON BOROUGH OF HOUNSLOW","PostcodeLocator":"TW4 7BH"},"geometry":{"x":-0.3821985875022217,"y":51.4666317243898}},{"attributes":{"Uprn":"100023405122","PaoStartNumber":null,"StreetDescription":"CAMBRIDGE ROAD","TownName":"HOUNSLOW","AdministrativeArea":"LONDON BOROUGH OF HOUNSLOW","PostcodeLocator":"TW4 7BH"},"geometry":{"x":-0.38243333019546377,"y":51.466466806658055}},{"attributes":{"Uprn":"100021542922","PaoStartNumber":144,"StreetDescription":"CAMBRIDGE ROAD","TownName":"HOUNSLOW","AdministrativeArea":"LONDON BOROUGH OF HOUNSLOW","PostcodeLocator":"TW4 7BH"},"geometry":{"x":-0.38480183659877226,"y":51.46625666417547}},{"attributes":{"Uprn":"100021542875","PaoStartNumber":74,"StreetDescription":"CAMBRIDGE ROAD","TownName":"HOUNSLOW","AdministrativeArea":"LONDON BOROUGH OF HOUNSLOW","PostcodeLocator":"TW4 7BH"},"geometry":{"x":-0.3821985875022217,"y":51.4666317243898}},{"attributes":{"Uprn":"100021542917","PaoStartNumber":128,"StreetDescription":"CAMBRIDGE ROAD","TownName":"HOUNSLOW","AdministrativeArea":"LONDON BOROUGH OF HOUNSLOW","PostcodeLocator":"TW4 7BH"},"geometry":{"x":-0.384246823870971,"y":51.466318258394196}},{"attributes":{"Uprn":"100021542903","PaoStartNumber":110,"StreetDescription":"CAMBRIDGE ROAD","TownName":"HOUNSLOW","AdministrativeArea":"LONDON BOROUGH OF HOUNSLOW","PostcodeLocator":"TW4 7BH"},"geometry":{"x":-0.38347530496454973,"y":51.466436214647985}},{"attributes":{"Uprn":"100021542891","PaoStartNumber":98,"StreetDescription":"CAMBRIDGE ROAD","TownName":"HOUNSLOW","AdministrativeArea":"LONDON BOROUGH OF HOUNSLOW","PostcodeLocator":"TW4 7BH"},"geometry":{"x":-0.383028739376071,"y":51.46656584126418}},{"attributes":{"Uprn":"100021542899","PaoStartNumber":106,"StreetDescription":"CAMBRIDGE ROAD","TownName":"HOUNSLOW","AdministrativeArea":"LONDON BOROUGH OF HOUNSLOW","PostcodeLocator":"TW4 7BH"},"geometry":{"x":-0.38330992657953355,"y":51.46647170229874}},{"attributes":{"Uprn":"100021542915","PaoStartNumber":124,"StreetDescription":"CAMBRIDGE ROAD","TownName":"HOUNSLOW","AdministrativeArea":"LONDON BOROUGH OF HOUNSLOW","PostcodeLocator":"TW4 7BH"},"geometry":{"x":-0.38405730127994897,"y":51.466344422080596}},{"attributes":{"Uprn":"10001271712","PaoStartNumber":98,"StreetDescription":"CAMBRIDGE ROAD","TownName":"HOUNSLOW","AdministrativeArea":"LONDON BOROUGH OF HOUNSLOW","PostcodeLocator":"TW4 7BH"},"geometry":{"x":-0.38296219641050205,"y":51.466574815159305}},{"attributes":{"Uprn":"100021542913","PaoStartNumber":120,"StreetDescription":"CAMBRIDGE ROAD","TownName":"HOUNSLOW","AdministrativeArea":"LONDON BOROUGH OF HOUNSLOW","PostcodeLocator":"TW4 7BH"},"geometry":{"x":-0.3838793220972253,"y":51.466369845331435}},{"attributes":{"Uprn":"100021542867","PaoStartNumber":64,"StreetDescription":"CAMBRIDGE ROAD","TownName":"HOUNSLOW","AdministrativeArea":"LONDON BOROUGH OF HOUNSLOW","PostcodeLocator":"TW4 7BH"},"geometry":{"x":-0.38181665932626224,"y":51.466684005068394}},{"attributes":{"Uprn":"100021542926","PaoStartNumber":152,"StreetDescription":"CAMBRIDGE ROAD","TownName":"HOUNSLOW","AdministrativeArea":"LONDON BOROUGH OF HOUNSLOW","PostcodeLocator":"TW4 7BH"},"geometry":{"x":-0.3849988071732138,"y":51.466223408022444}},{"attributes":{"Uprn":"100021542920","PaoStartNumber":132,"StreetDescription":"CAMBRIDGE ROAD","TownName":"HOUNSLOW","AdministrativeArea":"LONDON BOROUGH OF HOUNSLOW","PostcodeLocator":"TW4 7BH"},"geometry":{"x":-0.3844398590583197,"y":51.466274158174286}},{"attributes":{"Uprn":"100021542924","PaoStartNumber":148,"StreetDescription":"CAMBRIDGE ROAD","TownName":"HOUNSLOW","AdministrativeArea":"LONDON BOROUGH OF HOUNSLOW","PostcodeLocator":"TW4 7BH"},"geometry":{"x":-0.38490291428283696,"y":51.46624816492887}},{"attributes":{"Uprn":"100021542914","PaoStartNumber":122,"StreetDescription":"CAMBRIDGE ROAD","TownName":"HOUNSLOW","AdministrativeArea":"LONDON BOROUGH OF HOUNSLOW","PostcodeLocator":"TW4 7BH"},"geometry":{"x":-0.38397911995932066,"y":51.46635683308372}},{"attributes":{"Uprn":"100023404851","PaoStartNumber":76,"StreetDescription":"CAMBRIDGE ROAD","TownName":"HOUNSLOW","AdministrativeArea":"LONDON BOROUGH OF HOUNSLOW","PostcodeLocator":"TW4 7BH"},"geometry":{"x":-0.3822963348060751,"y":51.46659530526205}},{"attributes":{"Uprn":"100021542873","PaoStartNumber":72,"StreetDescription":"CAMBRIDGE ROAD","TownName":"HOUNSLOW","AdministrativeArea":"LONDON BOROUGH OF HOUNSLOW","PostcodeLocator":"TW4 7BH"},"geometry":{"x":-0.38214390587657543,"y":51.466630969927756}},{"attributes":{"Uprn":"100021542909","PaoStartNumber":116,"StreetDescription":"CAMBRIDGE ROAD","TownName":"HOUNSLOW","AdministrativeArea":"LONDON BOROUGH OF HOUNSLOW","PostcodeLocator":"TW4 7BH"},"geometry":{"x":-0.38367755680585735,"y":51.46641652198599}},{"attributes":{"Uprn":"100021542871","PaoStartNumber":68,"StreetDescription":"CAMBRIDGE ROAD","TownName":"HOUNSLOW","AdministrativeArea":"LONDON BOROUGH OF HOUNSLOW","PostcodeLocator":"TW4 7BH"},"geometry":{"x":-0.38199751879341026,"y":51.466658624684}},{"attributes":{"Uprn":"200003986690","PaoStartNumber":null,"StreetDescription":"WELLINGTON ROAD NORTH","TownName":"HOUNSLOW","AdministrativeArea":"LONDON BOROUGH OF HOUNSLOW","PostcodeLocator":"TW4 7BH"},"geometry":{"x":-0.3850126686295488,"y":51.46627935127267}},{"attributes":{"Uprn":"10001272702","PaoStartNumber":null,"StreetDescription":"TRINITY CLOSE","TownName":"HOUNSLOW","AdministrativeArea":"LONDON BOROUGH OF HOUNSLOW","PostcodeLocator":"TW4 7BH"},"geometry":{"x":-0.38477798869265694,"y":51.46640201112306}},{"attributes":{"Uprn":"10025164738","PaoStartNumber":null,"StreetDescription":"BOWNESS DRIVE","TownName":"HOUNSLOW","AdministrativeArea":"LONDON BOROUGH OF HOUNSLOW","PostcodeLocator":"TW4 7BH"},"geometry":{"x":-0.3829532752356606,"y":51.46629772887127}},{"attributes":{"Uprn":"100021542901","PaoStartNumber":108,"StreetDescription":"CAMBRIDGE ROAD","TownName":"HOUNSLOW","AdministrativeArea":"LONDON BOROUGH OF HOUNSLOW","PostcodeLocator":"TW4 7BH"},"geometry":{"x":-0.3834246863941074,"y":51.46644271064718}}]}
```

Comment: Could you create a fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use:

```
document.getElementById("extract").innerHTML = "-" + responseData.features[0].attributes.StreetDescription + "-";
```

instead of:

```
document.getElementById("extract").innerHTML = "-" + data.features[0].attributes.StreetDescription + "-";
```

since you've assigned `responseData`, not `data` to your `success` function.